# how to return values from mysql table with ajax and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am new to programing. I have one form to create Groups. It has two text fields Code Id and Code description. After submitting it showed me that the Code Id which i entered is already exist and if not it add one record in MySQL table. What I want that when I leave the Id text field at the same time with onchange event and Ajax to search table and alert if the Id already exit and at the same time fill name text box with description of that Code Id. How to do that? My code is

*HTML file*

```
...
</style>
<body>
    <H1>Create Grup</h1>
    <br>
    <form action="creategrup.php" method="post">

        <p>
            <label for="codigo">Grup Id:</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" autofocus="autofocus"
            maxlength="4" name="codigo" id="codigo">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="nombre">Grupo description:</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="nombre" id="nombre"">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

*And PHP is*

```
<?php
include 'connectdb.php';
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
$sql = "select codigogrupo,nombregrupo from grupo where
codigogrupo='$codigo'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) >0) {
    echo "<p><h1><b>Grup Id $codigo allready exist....</h1></b></p><br>";
    echo "<a href='creategrup.html'>Go Back</a>";
}
else {
    mysqli_query($conn, "insert into grupo(codigogrupo,nombregrupo)
    values('$codigo','$nombre')");

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0){
        echo "<p><h1><b>Grup  $nombre added</h1></b></p>";
        echo "<a href='creategrup.html'>Go Back</a>";
    } else {
        echo "Grup not added<br>";
        echo mysqli_error ($conn);
    }
}   
?>
```

*Connectdb.php*

```
<?php

    $servername = "server name";
    $username = "user name";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "database";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **already exist** message so that may be confirm that there is another data with same id. For further assistance please knock me

Comment: This code is working fine, only I wanted to know how to add onchange event with first textbox and when user left the field at the same time it shows the message that code that user entered exist not after pressing Submit. And at the same time if code exist it shows the code description in name text box.